# Extension setter is not recognized if getter exists

Tags: dart

(Dart 2.10.4)
I've noticed a weird behavior when implementing an extension setter. If a getter with the same name as the setter exists in the original class, then the setter in unrecognized.

[image: Works as intended]

[image]

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a deliberate design decision.

Dart generally treats getters and setters with the same base-name as being two sides of the same one thing, so if an interface has a getter (or setter), it's considered as having that *property* in general, and then a corresponding extension setter (or getter) won't be applicable.

The only place you can really-really treat a getter and setter as separate is when a subclass overrides only one of them from the superclass. In almost all other cases, having a getter or setter means having the property.

The reason for the design is, basically, that if you write `++i`, or `i += 1`, or `i = i + 1`, the read and the write *must* refer to the *same variable*. Anything else is going to be incredibly fragile and error-prone.

If you have

```dart
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
class C {
  static final int j = 1;
  final int i = 2;
  foo() {
    i += 1;
    j += 1;
  }
}
```

the `i += 1` will *not* read the final `C.i` and write the top-level variable,
and the `j += 1` will *not* read the final static `C.j` and write the top-level variable.
Instead looking up `i` in `foo` will always find the `final int i = 2;` of `C` and treat `i += 1;` as `this.i += 1;`, and similarly `j += 1;` means `C.j += 1;`.

For this purpose, a getters/setter in a static extension is considered a different variable than the instance variable of the class.

Comment: If  "it's considered as having that property in general, and then a corresponding extension setter (or getter) won't be applicable", then why would a regular non extension setter (or getter) be applicable?

And if it's a deliberate design decision, what's the benefit of it?

Comment: The benefit is a simpler model where an interface is considered as either having a member of a given name or not. Having a setter without a getter is exceedingly rare, and not a case that is designed for, so it's more about whether the is a variable of that name at all, and *then* whether that variable is final or not. For subclasses overriding, it's not about interface modelling as much as it's about implementation inheritance. You can *choose* to inherit a getter or setter from the superclass, and you could always use `get foo => super.foo`, so it's easier to make no declaration do that.